# Why Hindu Gods do not protect Hindus anymore in the modern day?

Tags: gods, devi, bhakti, iskcon, prahlada

I read a book on atrocities performed on Hindus in the past 200 years by invaders. By reading it, anybody's faith will be shaken to the core.

For example, there is one account was of a Muslim invader asking a Vedic priest why does he pray to Agni, to which he replied that because Agni is God, that's why he prays. To this Muslim invader burnt him alive and asked others what sort of God it is which can't even protect its devotees. This is one of thousands of incidents where devotees and temples were desecrated and nothing Divine saved them.

A few days ago, ISKCON devotees in Bangladesh were peacefully praying to Goddess Durga who is known to kill demons. I know ISKCON people personally, I know for sure that they have a lot of devotion. Barbarians attacked them, desecrated the moorti, killed the priest. And Hindu Gods did nothing. Therefore I ask, have Hindu Gods abandoned Hindus?

Or is our devotion not good enough? Or are the account of Puranas false which say that God even appears from a pillar if a devotee is in trouble? Or is that just for Prahlāda and other special people?

Comment: Can you specify the devotion in detail? Everywhere they are expecting money. One does pooja for the sake of doing pooja, running short of time to office or to move to another place within short span of time....

Comment: Gods always don't come and help their devotees at every instance of trouble. It is only when the evil has surpassed all levels of atrocities and it can't be no longer handled/defeated by us God comes and helps us but not before that point.

Comment: I came across a video on the history of contraception in Youtube & there was this story from the Old Testament-a man had sex with his sister-in-law & to prevent her pregnancy, he performed coitus interrruptus for which he was killed by God by striking thunderbolt. Do you want God to become this sort of overbearing parent ?

Comment: This has suprised me also. It seems like the gods are extremely reluctant to help out when needed.

Comment: @Wikash surprised me that gods are also reluctant to eliminate athiests

Comment: @Rickross moreover whatever is happening it is happening as per karma. Fault lies within us. Not others. That is why we need to read histories of devotees who had darshan and what was the devotees nature in their life and if you see them devotees never had darshan of God just like that. It's under extreme peak of devotion where Supreme has given its vision. Not before that.  Requires extreme tapasya bhakti

Comment: @Parabrahman Yjoti why though? The scriptures do not speak of hate against atheists.

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti Proving his existence seems a more sensible course of action

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa, poof already exists, people who claim otherwise simply havent verified it.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa proof already exists. Methods given as well to see the supreme. Follow the way shown. You will see

Answer (score 3):

God does not normally interfere in worldly affairs.

> Resorting to Prakrti, Nature, which is My own Power, I send forth
> again and again this multitude of beings that are without any freedom,
> owing to Nature's sway over them.

**Gita 9.8**

> These activities do not in any way bind Me, because **I remain detached
> like one unconcerned in their midst.**

**Gita 9.9**

> Under My direction and control, Nature brings out this mighty universe
> of living and non-living beings. Thus does the wheel of this world
> revolve.

**Gita 9.10**

**When does God intervene?**

God intervenes for great devotees.

> Whoever being devoted to me solely, engage themselves always in
> contemplation and worship of Me - to such eversteadfast devotees I
> ensure the procurement of all their wants (salvation) and the
> preservation of their assets (worldly interests).

**Gita 9.22**

God also intervenes in worldly affairs when dharma is in decline and adharma is in ascendance.

> Whenever there is decline of Dharma and ascendance of Adharma, then, o
> scion of the Bharata race! I manifest (incarnate) Myself in a body.

**Gita 4.7**

> For the protection of the good, for the destruction of the evil, and
> for the establishment of Dharma, I am born from age to age.

**Gita 4.8**

Answer (score 2):

The Gods do protect us if we have that level of faith. I had a personal experience with Sri Hari. A few men verbally abused me, and I was worried that they would hurt me. I didn't know anybody around who could help.

So, not knowing what to do, I just closed my eyes and prayed to the Divine. In my mind, I told the Divine - I'm okay with whatever happens. I will deal with it. But, what kind of behavior is this with your devotee Sri Hari?

As if by magic, those men got panicked and stopped troubling me. Some of those men even looked scared. Even today, I had no idea what happened that day. Some say that they saw a glow on my face, which scared the men!

I'm not someone who blindly believes in God, but I chant mantras with utmost faith every day. I'm a resident of the US and was visiting India when this happened! Based on my personal experience, there is some Divine element out there. Just that people don't have a depth of Bhakti to experience the Divine anymore.

Comment: It could be that the persons thought you were mentally ill. That has nothing to do with a god.

Comment: Totally! We're all mentally ill in our own ways! Some are mentally ill in Bhakti. Some are mentally ill in searching for money. A few more are mentally ill in speaking ill of others. The list is endless! 

Comment: Sure and talking complete gibberish in front of people increases the chance of coming over as mentally ill.

Comment: Totally agree about the gibberish.. case in point - see @Wikash_'s comment above

Answer (score 1):

The answer : We are living in Kali Yuga, and it was even told by God himself that devotees will be hunted down like animals,and mlecchas will take over and ruin everything.

> For example, there is one account was of a Muslim invader asking a
> Vedic priest why does he pray to Agni, to which he replied that
> because Agni is God, that's why he prays. To this Muslim invader burnt
> him alive and asked others what sort of God it is which can't even
> protect its devotees. This is one of thousands of incidents where
> devotees and temples were desecrated and nothing Divine saved them

There are many ways to answer this:

> “The people of Kali Yuga are stimulated by the lowest instincts. They
> chose false ideas and concepts over the authentic ones, **they have no**
> **hesitation in persecuting the wise**,the envy torments them,
> negligence, disease, hunger and fear will spread". [Linga Purana]

From another answer, I am pasting this [Credit : User Ikshvaku on Stack Exchange]

> From the Vishnu Purana on the symptoms of Kali Yuga:
>
> The people of the various countries intermingling with them will
> follow their example, and **the barbarians [mlecchas]  being powerful in**
> **the patronage of the princes, whilst purer tribes [Vedic civilization]
> are neglected the people will perish**.
>
> Translator H.H. Wilson says in the footnote to that verse:
>
> The commentator, having no doubt the existing state of things in view,
> interprets the passage somewhat differently: the original is, ###. The
> comment explains 'strong', and adds, the Mlechchhas will be in the
> centre, and the Áryyas at the end:' meaning, if any thing, that the
> unbelievers are in the heart of the country, and the Hindus on the
> borders: ... All that the text intends, is to represent infidels and
> foreigners high in power, and the Brahmans depressed.

Also, As mentioned in the Śivapurāṇa 1.1.

> Accordingly, “at the advent of the terrible age of Kali [kaliyuga] men
> have become devoid of merits. They are engaged in evil ways of life.
> They have turned their faces from truthful avocations. They are
> engaged in caluminating others. They covet other men’s wealth. Their
> attention is diverted to other men’s wives. Injuring others has become
> their chief aim. They view the physical body as the soul, deluded as
> they are; **they are atheists of mere brutish sense**; they hate their
> parents; their wives are goddesses unto them; they are slaves to lust.

Also, Skanda Purana Chapter 27 says

> 73. **In this Yuga, O excellent one among Suras, Dharma is tormented by Adharma, truth by untruth and kings by thieves perpetually**.
>
> 75-77. In Kaliyuga, **righteous men, men dedicated to truth, persons of
> full control over the sense-organs, persons of discretion, quiescent
> ones and those devoted to the good of others—all these suffer**.
>
> Mental anguish, ailments, afflictions of mysterious origin—all are
> always prevalent in Kaliyuga causing misery to the good.

**Hence, persecution of those who follow vedic rites is a sure occurence in Kali Yuga. This cannot be changed.**

Coming back to this story of yours :

> For example, there is one account was of a Muslim invader asking a
> Vedic priest why does he pray to Agni, to which he replied that
> because Agni is God, that's why he prays. To this Muslim invader burnt
> him alive and asked others what sort of God it is which can't even
> protect its devotees. This is one of thousands of incidents where
> devotees and temples were desecrated and nothing Divine saved them.

There have also been instances of people slaughtering muslims and urinating on the kaaba for 20-40 years. Muslims usually use the stories of invaders to taunt hindus, whilst their sites of pilgrimage were also sacked.

> To this Muslim invader burnt him alive and asked others what sort of
> God it is which can't even protect its devotees.

In the year 906 A.D. the leader of the Qarmatians, Abu Taher Bin Hassan Al-Qurmuti, led 700 horsemen into Mecca, massacred the Pilgrims, uncovered the Kaaba, and Urinated on it, took the black stone, and went over the top of the Kaaba and Said,

> I am in God and God is in me. Where is your God? I am your great God.
> Where are the Birds of God (Tayr al ababeel) that protect the Kaaba?
> Where are the Stones of Fire (Hijara min sejeel)?

If muslims use this incident somehow, just remember the incidents after 906 AD.