# how the Gods permitted the desecration of Somnath, Kashi and Mathura temple by the invaders

Tags: gods, temple

This has vexed me for long. When the Hindu Gods were so powerful how could the Muslim invaders destroy the temples like Somnath, Kashi and Mathura where God were supposed to be living there after proper installation as pran pratistha in the Idols installed there. the shiv linga was broken and pieces taken away.
how even the devotees in the campus of the Somnath temple could not avoid being massacred by Ghaznavi's forces?

Comment: This question has already been answered. See https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/49356/why-hindu-gods-do-not-protect-hindus-anymore-in-the-modern-day/49375#49375

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why did India lose to foreign invaders?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21916/why-did-india-lose-to-foreign-invaders)

Comment: Sawmi Vivekananda also thought the same while visiting Kshirabhavani in Kashmir & lamented at the fact that he couldn't sacrifice his life in preventing desecration of her temple. At that time he heard a female voice saying, "Am I your saviour or you my saviour ? I wanted to live in a ruined temple, so the Yavanas desecrated it. Am I not capable of erecting a seven-storied golden temple in this spot at this very moment if I wish it ?" After this incident, he reversed his views on incorporeal voices.

Comment: This does not answer the question. it suggests that God wanted the temples to be desecrated and allowed it to happen. What about the faith and pride of millions of the devotees?

Comment: @sanjeev - for the same reason Krishna allowed Kamsa to torment his fellow cowherds, or Rama allowed Rakshasas to tear limb-to-limb Rishis in Dandakararnya forest, or Vamana allowed Bali to drive Indra away from heaven. Assume for a minute, that in times without an avatara, all the Asuras/Rakshasas who tormented people did not get punished. Now how to punish them ? After many births those Asuras will take birth in human form. And then they will be massacred by tyrants. In future, these tyrants will also take birth, and be massacred by others -see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/37351/4435

Comment: @sanjeev Not even a single blade of leaf can move without the Paramapurusha's will. If you want to imply that desecration of tirthas was against His will, then you are contradicting the Ekamevādvitiyam notion of Brahman. Secondly, the notion that God is the cause of all good & He can't cause any evil is a completely Abrahamic notion. Brahman is above all notions of dualities (including that of good & evil). It is impossible for the human senses to perceive Brahman's will.

Comment: Thirdly, within each hairpit of Mahavishnu lies a brahmanda, each consisting of the 14 lokas (including Bhuloka). The Puranas repeatedly state that even if it is possible to count the number of sand grains, it's impossible to clearly ascertain the exact number of brahmandas. The glory of Parabrahman isn't affected by the slightest if certain inhabitants of single Bhuloka becomes hostile to His self-respledent glory. But in order to to be relieved from the twin cycles of karma & birth-death-rebirth, it's necessary for us to take refuge of Parabrahman.

Answer (score 1):

> Then Swamiji said that on the way back he returned to Srinagar by the common route by which the pilgrims return. A few days after returning to Srinagar, he went to visit Kshir Bhavani Devi and staying there for seven days worshipped the Devi and made Homa to her with offerings of Kshira (condensed milk). Every day he used to worship the Devi with a maund of Kshira as offering.

> One day, while worshipping, the thought arose in Swamiji's mind: "Mother Bhavani has been manifesting Her Presence here for untold years. The Mohammedans came and destroyed her temple, yet the people of the place did nothing to protect Her. Alas, if I were then living I could never have borne it silently."

> When, thinking in this strain, his mind was much oppressed with sorrow and anguish, **he distinctly heard the voice of the Mother saying, "It was according to My desire that the Mohammedans destroyed this temple. It is My desire that I should live in a dilapidated temple, otherwise, can I not immediately erect a seven-storeyed temple of gold here if I like? What can you do? Shall I protect you or shall you protect me!"**

> Swamiji said, "Since hearing that divine voice, I cherish no more plans. The idea of building Maths etc. I have given up; as Mother wills, so it will be."

Later he said

> Swamiji gravely said, "Whether it be internal or external, if you actually hear with your ears such a disembodied voice, as I have done, can you deny it and call it false? Divine Voices are actually heard, just as you and I are talking."

Reference - [The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda/Volume 7/Conversations And Dialogues/IV](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_7/Conversations_And_Dialogues/IV)

Answer (score -3):

The [Bhavishya Purana](https://vedpuran.files.wordpress.com/2016/07/pratisarga-parva-third-khand.pdf) details a conversation between Gabriel (who we can safely assume is the evil Kali) and king Bhoja. Gabriel is called Pisacha, possibly actually Paiśāca in Sanskrit, outside the quotes. Gabriel is probably lying about some things, but that does not matter for this point.

> Sootjee said:-"In deep at night, the illusionist Dev pisacha, came towards King
> Bhoj and said: - Rajan! Your Arya Dharma is greatest above every other Dharma. I
> am only propagating this Dharma by the order of "Isha"**. The Dharma as it
> goes:-" Being in my Dharma, one have to cut his genital, he will have no shikha
> (the small amount of hair tied backward of head that belongs to Brahmin), He will
> talk bigger, shout loudly and will be omnivorous. Without kaultantra, they will eat
> animals, and they will perform purified act with the musala or a pestle as you
> purify your things with kusa. Therefore, they will be called as musalmaan, the
> people who will belong to this Dharma will pollute every pure Dharma. Likewise I
> will spread this paisachik Dharma," and he dictated his Dharma to the king."

Later, Gabriel, is also called the servant of Raudra. There should be an "and" to separate Muhammad and Gabriel, as they are clearly different people in the rest of the text. As a side note, it is weird the text says "seems", when this is not someone quoted.

> Shobha, who **seems** not to have benefited from this edifying discourse, has
> become an almswoman and set herself to meditating on "the heroic Mahaamada,
> the **Pisacha servant of Raudra**"

Raudra is notable for Arjuna mistaking it for Rudra in the fall of Hiranyapura story, clearly showing he does not know what is going on. As for a real reference, the best seems to be from the Bhavishya Purana itself. Earlier (this book really expects you to jump all over the place) there is a snake called Raudra. He seems to be pretty evil and hence is possibly a reference to the snake from the Garden of Eden (either counting as a third reference to Christianity or one for Judaism).

> **Raudra snake** replied: - “Hey low caste snake! By getting the body of this very
> king, sheltering myself in it, I get the happiness of the world. Hence roguish and
> wicked! How will I leave the body of the king, because, due to any reason of
> sadness only, one can left his own home! The king is foolish, because, why he
> didn't give boiled oil in your shelter? "

Anyway, all of this is to say the reason for the desecration of temples is because of an evil snake, who is possible the inspiration for the evil snake in the Bible, who has an evil Deva Gabriel at his command.